# highcharts scrollbar labels not appearing

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i am trying to put labels on x-axis for the charts mentioned below.
even the labels that i want to display are taken from the database and displayed. for each value of y-axis there is a repective x-axis. so i want like when i hover on the point x-axis value : y-axis value. it should appear like this.

If anyone had tried this earlier, please help.

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    scrollbar: {
        barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        barBorderRadius: 7,
        barBorderWidth: 0,
        buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        buttonBorderWidth: 0,
        buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
        buttonBorderRadius: 7,
        rifleColor: 'yellow',
        trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
        trackBorderWidth: 1,
        trackBorderColor: 'silver',
        trackBorderRadius: 7
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
 
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tooltip`'s `formatter`  [(Highcharts API here)](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {return this.x+" : "+this.y}
}
```

Assuming you have the `names` you want to give to the x-Axis in an `array`, this code should work:

Javascript:

```
var namesArray = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += namesArray[this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)] +" : "+this.y;
            });

            return s;
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: [3, 5, 6, 7] 
    }]
});
```

Please notice I added `namesArray` as an example here. 
What the `tooltip` function does is the following:

- it declares a String
- it loops through all of your `Highstock` points
- for each point, it gets the `index` of the point in `series.data` and gets the same `index` from `namesArray`. This should achieve the thing you need.

Comment: i tried this, only date which is displayed in the x-axis is appearing but i want a different array of names to be displayed or showed when hover on the point instead of date pre-exissting on the x-axis.

Comment: @Nagesh I'm not entirely sure what you are asking then. Your question stated `so i want like when i hover on the point x-axis value : y-axis value.`  and this answer gives you this format. Could you please elaborate? (What different array of names? What's the variable name we are talking about?)

Comment: Thanks. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>. please click on the above link, in that link only date and one y-axis value is taken. when i tried to display both values x-axis : y-axis it is showing date : y-axis value. where as i have some name in database corresponding to that date and y-axis value, that name: y-axis values i want to display. but the above link is not accenting the names in place of date so i am not able to display name instead of date. This is my problem. please help.

Comment: @Nagesh this is your imported data set. It doesn't make it clear to me what you want to appear on the x-axis, still.

Comment: @Nagesh so if I understand correctly, you have an array with labels `array = [ "1", "2", "3"]` you want to match to point 1, 2 and 3 in your graph? (and so on)

Comment: you are almost there, whatever graph displaying is right. but i want to display name corresponding to the date in y-axis instead of showing date. i.e like name : y-axis value.

Comment: @Nagesh Where do you store those names? Are they in your `series`? I'm a bit confused as to how you want to match said names

Comment: i tried to store the name in series but the graph is not supporting, it is taking only date, and  one value. so i am struck. when i tried to add a third varible in the series, graph is not showing at all.

Comment: i have stored those names  in separate file too as an array.

Comment: @Nagesh I think I understood you. I've edited my answer with the basic thing you should do to get your names to be presented in the graph, but you will need to generate the real `array` yourself still.

Comment: @Nagesh Are you sure your array is just as long as your dataset? If I paste this in a JSFiddle it works. I myself trimmed down the dataset used in your example as it had thousands of points.

Comment: yes, the array is same as dataset but it is not showing it says undefined. could you please share the jsfiddle i will try it once.

Comment: lt me try one again

Comment: i tried many times i tried to load it from different file and also tried by pasting the same data inside the file. but it still says undefined.

Comment: @Nagesh I can't help you any further because I do not have access to the file. Theoretically speaking, my answer should work for your problem, if you manage to parse the names inside the array like I did in my example. (I assume the fiddle did what you wanted?)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort, its working for smaller data but it is not working for larger data. If needed i will share the data file.